# Hive - convert Int to varchar and concatenate

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I have 2 columns I want to convert to varchars and concatenate to place them in one column:

How would I do this in Hive? I keep getting issues when I try the normal way in sql...

```
round(min(temp) over (partition by temp2, temp3) min,
round(max(temp)) over (partition by temp2, temp3) max

*original columns*
min    max
 0    100
```

=====================================

```
*new column*
min-max
$0-$100
```

Answer:

This worked for me.....

`concat('$',cast(round(min(temp)) as string), ' - $', cast(round(max(temp)) as string)) over (partition by temp2, temp3) newColumn`

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-TypeConversionFunctions

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select ('$' || round(min(temp) over (partition by temp2, temp3) || '-' ||
        '$' || round(max(temp)) over (partition by temp2, temp3)
       ) as minmax
```

Comment: thanx....following the link above I found the concat and cast functions.  This is what I used and it worked:   `concat('$',cast(round(min(temp)) as string), ' - $', cast(round(max(temp)) as string)) over (partition by temp2, temp3) newColumn`

Comment: That should also work, but `concat()` should convert the data types automatically to strings.

Comment: In HIVE, concat() does not convert to string, but instead gives an error.